# Can Redis be built into a Java Struts web application?

Tags: redis

I've heard a lot about Redis cache and would like to start using it in my Apache Struts web application however I am looking for a lightweight caching engine where I don't need to install anything on my application server.

Can Redis be built into my web application by including some jars in my web app libraries?

I'm asking because so far all that I have come across in way of instructions of getting started with Redis seems to suggest that I need to install something on my application server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can (basically you can build anything into a Struts application) but it's not a Jar. You need to run a binary somewhere. Redis itself is a server application that requires a client component for communication.

Comment: The OP did explicitly say they don't want to install anything

Comment: The OP has two questions in it.

Comment: Am I being blind then? I only see one question

Comment: I cannot give you a sophisticated answer to your question, but I see "Can Redis be built into a Java Struts web application?" and "Can Redis be built into my web application by including some jars in my web app libraries?".

Comment: That's the same question, one of them is merely the title